# Skip function invocation and return value with custom function filter

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am wanting to share some logic between multiple functions which now seems to be partially achievable by using [Function Filters](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Function-Filters) within azure functions however in certain cases I don't want to continue execution of the function and be able to return a result back to the binding provider (same as returning a result from the function it's self).

Taking a look at the code the only way to short circuit the calling of the inner `IFunctionInvoker` within `FunctionInvocationFilterInvoker` is to throw an exception inside the custom invocation filter. The only problem with this approach is that the exception will bubble up to the host and cause a failure/retries etc.. somewhere else.

Also taking this approach doesn't allow me to set another return value back binding provider. I did see that we could wrap this in our own `IFunctionInvoker` but I was wondering if there was a better way to achieve this?

[Code executing filters](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/3696dd28df66996b1adcc0697f0d0f88f865cb64/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Executors/FunctionExecutor.cs#L1163)

Comment: In your case, is it possible to write logic to control invaction functions in the Azure function? (According parameter message info to invaction correspondent function. )

Comment: execution of the function is called here - https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/3696dd28df66996b1adcc0697f0d0f88f865cb64/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Executors/FunctionExecutor.cs#L569

Comment: I was expecting a `result` (filterContext.Result) object that I could possibly return, just like ActionFilters in MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible yet, but this is something we'll definitely enable. We're tracking this capability in our repo [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1314).

Comment: Ended up looking in to this myself and raised the first issue with the sketched out PR :-) thanks for answer though forgot asked this